# Is every subgroup of a free abelian group a direct summand?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

My guess is *NO*, because take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $F=2\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup but not a direct summand.

Comment: i think you've answered the question. that's a nice simple example to bear in mind. more generally, if every subgroup were a direct summand, then every quotient group would also be a direct summand. and this is counter to the theorem that every group is a quotient of a free group

Comment: your example says, a subgroup of finite index in free abelian group will never be  a direct summand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, because take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $F=2\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup but not a direct summand. It is not a direct summand because if $\mathbb{Z}$ was $\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z} \oplus H$

Then since the intersection of $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $H$ is trivial, $H$ must consist of all odd numbers plus the zero. But that does not constitute a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

That every subgroup of an abelian group $A$ has a direct summand is equivalent to saying that $A$ is semisimple as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. As you have already noticed $\mathbb{Z}$ itself is not semisimple.

If $A$ is an abelian group such that some element $a \in A$ has infinite order, then $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the subgroup generated by $a$. Because submodules of semisimple modules are also semisimple it follows that $A$ cannot be semisimple as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

As a special case of this we get that the trivial group is the only free abelian group which is a semisimple $\mathbb{Z}$-module, because each other free abelian group contains an element of infinite order.

Comment: This implies that not every morphism defined in $F$, which is a subgroup of a free abelian group $G$, can be extended to the whole group $G$, right?  At least the same example works, I think.

Because that was my first question, if every morphism defined in a subgroup of a free abelian group can be extended.

Comment: You can just reuse your example: The map $2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, $n \mapsto \frac{1}{2}n$ can not be extended to $\mathbb{Z}$. To extend a group homomorphism $F \to A$ to $G$ we probably need (at least) some kind of divisibility conditions for $A$.

Comment: whoa thanks friend

Comment: If I am not mistaken this may work for divisible abelian groups: If $\varphi \colon  F \to D$ with $D$ divisible then $D$ carries a unique $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure, and $\varphi$ induces a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $\phi \colon \mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} F \to D$. This can then be extended to $\Phi \colon \mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} G \to D$ (because we are dealing with $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces). Regarding $F$ and $G$ as abelian subgroups of $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} F$ and $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} G$ the restriction $\Phi|_G \colon G \to D$ then extends $\varphi$.